# List the factors of a non-prime number

Tags: ruby, math

My goal is to display if a number is prime, and if it is not, list all of its factors. If I input 6, the program should return:

```
6 is not a prime number => 2, 3
```

Here is what I have so far:

```
puts "Enter a number: "
  num = gets
  num = num.to_i

def prime(num)
  is_prime = true
  for i in 2..num-1
    if num % i == 0
      is_prime = false
    end
  end
  if is_prime
    puts "#{num} is prime!"
  else
    puts "#{num} is not prime!"
  end
end
prime(num)
```

I tried making a `while` loop for this but I can't seem to make it work. I'm not sure if I am using the `num%i==0` formula correctly. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you just need to list all the factors or also the correct exponent?

Comment: The `2..num-1` probably does not have the correct precedence. `2..(num-1)` would be correct, but Ruby permits a shortcut. One more dot: `2...num`

Comment: I just need to list the factors Yunnosch.

Comment: "I can't seem to make it work." is not a precise enough error description for us to help you. *What* doesn't work? *How* doesn't it work? What trouble do you have with your code? Do you get an error message? What is the error message? Is the result you are getting not the result you are expecting? What result do you expect and why, what is the result you are getting and how do the two differ? Is the behavior you are observing not the desired behavior? What is the desired behavior and why, what is the observed behavior, and in what way do they differ?

Comment: Can you provide a *precise* specification of what it is that you want to happen, including any and all rules, exceptions from those rules, corner cases, special cases, boundary cases, and edge cases? Can you provide sample inputs and outputs demonstrating what you expect to happen, both in normal cases, and in all the exceptions, corner cases, special cases, boundary cases, and edge cases?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Homework hint 1)
You need to change the following things in order to get all the factors:

- do not stop as soon as you find one factor
  (which your prime-finder code inefficiently does not do anyway...)
- print each factor you find

If you also need the correct exponent you further need to

- check for each found factor whether it is still a factor after dividing by it,
  this needs to be done in a loop

Homework hint 2)
In order to get a specific desired output, print the decoration (e.g. "," and newlines) explicitly when it is needed.
Printing the statement first and only once can be done by using a flag for "already printed" and checking it before printing the statement in the loop.

(I assume that this is a homework question and am therefor intentionally not giving a complete solution, according to the compromise desccribed here [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions)
Thank you for not minding my assumption, or so I gather from your accepting my answer. In case it is not about homework I assume that you appreciated the help and the way of helping, in spite of my mistake.)

Comment: wouldn't this return factors like this
2
3
if so how would i keep them on the same line with commas separating them

Comment: I think it would and that it is what you want. Did I misunderstand something? If the exact format of the output is important you should stress that in the question and define the desired output more clearly.

Comment: Why do you think this is a homework question? Might the asker just be curious and/or learning Ruby on their own? Even if it is homework, Ruby's [policy on homework](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) is: "Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it."  (Note that this does not necessarily mean that code must be provided). The Community Wiki at the link you give merely reflects the views of some SO members.

Comment: I assume it, for the kind of question, the way of asking and because of the descripion of an attempt to change to a different loop, though it already does. It is an assumption and i say so. Finally I now assume taht I was right, for the simple reason that OP accepted, after one iteration of asking for more help and getting it. And yes, the link I provided is to  a discussion, not a definition of mandatory rule. It also describes different opinions. I usually add a "the compromise described here", when referring it, which admitteldy I did not here.

Comment: Note that I (in a comment to one of the other answers) only asked about awareness, while stating that I accept other opinions than mine. I think knowing the (in my opinion balanced) representation of different opinions on the topic is valuable, indepedently on which opininon anybody holds. @CarySwoveland

Answer (score 1):

If permitted to do so, use the Standard Library class [`Prime`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.5.0/libdoc/prime/rdoc/Prime.html).

```
require 'prime'

def is_prime? n
  n.prime? ? n : Prime.prime_division(n)
end

p is_prime? 6   #=> [[2, 1], [3, 1]]
p is_prime? 11  #=> 11
p is_prime? 100 #=> [[2, 2], [5, 2]]
```

Comment: I will accept your opinion on how to answer homework questions (assuming you also have the impression that this is one), though disagreeing with it. But do you know the discussion on it? I.e. are you aware of the meta question I linked?

Comment: @Yunnosch I may have skimmed through the discussion before, but worth another look- thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
require 'prime'

def factors(n)
  first, *rest =
    Prime.prime_division(n).map { |n,power| [n].product((0..power).to_a) }
   first.product(*rest).map { |a| a.reduce(1) { |t,(n,power)| t * n**power } }       
end
```

Let's use this method to compute the factors of 1500.

```
factors 1500
  #=> [ 1,  5,  25,  125,
  #     3, 15,  75,  375,
  #     2, 10,  50,  250,
  #     6, 30, 150,  750,
  #     4, 20, 100,  500,
  #    12, 60, 300, 1500]
```

Note that

```
Prime.prime_division(1500)
  #=> [[2, 2], [3, 1], [5, 3]]
```

and

```
Prime.prime_division(500).map { |n,power| [n].product((0..power).to_a) }
  #=> [[[2, 0], [2, 1], [2, 2]], [[5, 0], [5, 1], [5, 2], [5, 3]]]
```

Moreover, `factors(n).size` equals `2` if and only if `n` is prime. For example,

```
factors(37)
  #=> [1, 37]
Prime.prime?(37)
  #=> true
```

See [Prime::prime_division](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.0/libdoc/prime/rdoc/Prime.html#method-i-prime_division).

Comment: Using `Prime` in homework is cheating, don't you think? :)

Comment: @Sergio, I don't know and I don't care, even if it is homework, which is not a given. I only want to show how the problem can be solved in a Ruby-like way. I'm sure there are plenty of other complete solutions to this question  the asker could find by Googling. Let me try.: hey, Google, what do have for "ruby factors" site:stackoverflow.com"? Yeah, the first hit is a complete solution (but I don't like it as well as what I have), and there are other complete solutions.

Comment: I can only assume that the downvote is not for the quality of the answer, but because the dv-er doesn't like the fact that I offered a solution to what they think is a homework question. In my book that's not a valid reason.

Comment: Wasn't me, btw. :)